# Macbook is flashing Apple Logo, Forbidden Sign, Question Mark

Tags: macos, disk-utility, startup, ssd, high-sierra

I have a 13" MacBook Pro, mid 2012, in which I installed a Crucial 1TB SSD, and installed macOS Sierra, then upgraded to High Sierra.

Recently it would not boot after waking up from sleep, then I had to restart.

For 2 times it showed up the forbidden sign. In those situations I turned off and on again and everything worked just fine.

Last time it happened I was not successful, so I tried:

- reset NVRAM, holding <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>together, on statup;
- reset SMC, holding left <kbd>ShiftControl</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> together, with laptop switched off then turning it on;
- reset SMC, holding power button for 8sec while turning it on;
- go to recovery mode ans reinstall macOS High Sierra from USB drive
- go to recovery mode, format disk, even erasing partition, and creating new ones, then installing High Sierra,
- go to recovery mode, tried the same as previous fix, but installing macOS Mountain Lion, from local/ROM (I guess?) drive - not from DVD or any wired connect disk.

While booting, system still flashes "Apple logo", "forbidden sign" and "folder with ?", by this same order, sequentially, quickly.

Nothing worked so far.
Tried system diagnostics from Apple (turn on + press <kbd>D</kbd>), performing exhaustive test, and it is passing all tests.

Does anyone have any clue?
Appreciate all the help!